# Unable to show image in notification android using firebase

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing trouble to get picture (url) in notification android; even though image url is not null.

Also, image url gets converted to bitmap successfully but it is not showing in notification.

Below is my code. Please someone help; i am kinda stuck here and unable to find a working solution.

```
 private void getNotification(String title, String message, String imageUrl){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    final NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                    | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    Bitmap largeImage = null;
    if (imageUrl != null) {
        try {
            largeImage = Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).get();
            if (largeImage!=null){
                notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(largeImage));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: have you check your imageURL if is correct ?

Comment: yes, the imageUrl is correct

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the image is downloaded, also add a notification channel, otherwise, your notification will not be shown to oreo>=devices, So add an `AsyncTask`:

```
doAsync {
            var bmp: Bitmap? = null
            try {
                if (notificationModel.notifyImage.trim().isNotEmpty())
                    bmp = getBitmap(BuildConfig.IMAGE_URL + notificationModel.notifyImage)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.v("bmpDoInBck", "" + e)
            }

            applicationContext.runOnUiThread {
                val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

                try {

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, notificationModel.notifyTitle, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
                        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
                    }

                    if (bmp != null) {
                        notificationBuilder.setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bmp).setSummaryText(notificationModel.notifyDesc.trim()))
                    } else {
                        val textStyle = NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(description)
                        textStyle.setBigContentTitle(notificationModel.notifyTitle)
                        notificationBuilder.setStyle(textStyle)
                    }


                    notificationManager.notify(notificationModel.notifyId.toInt(), notificationBuilder.build())
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.v("NotifyingException", "" + e)
                }

            }
        }
```

Copy this method:

```
private fun getBitmap(url: String): Bitmap? {
        var newUrl: URL? = null
        try {
            newUrl = URL(url)
        } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        try {
            val bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newUrl!!.openConnection().getInputStream())
            return if (bmp == null) null else Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 700, 350, true)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.v("BitmapException", "" + e)
        }

        return null
    }
```